# Es posible relacionar una Clave Compuesta como Clave Foranea en otra tabla?

Tags: mysql

tengo la duda de si se puede relacionar una tabla con otra Tabla que tenga una Clave Primaria compuesta por dos campos. Uso PHPmyAdmin y uso sentencias SQL.

Seria Asi...

Tabla A ( id, nombre, ... )
Tabla B ( id, nombre, ... )
Tabla C ( id, nombre, ... )

Tabla D ( id Tabla A, id Tabla B ) --clave compuesta por dos claves foraneas

Tabla E ( id Tabla C, **aca iria la clave compuesta de la tabla D** )

Ejemplo:

```
> CREATE TABLE Artistas (
>     id_Artista INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>     nombre_Artista VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL );

CREATE TABLE Obras (
    id_Obra INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_Obra VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Teatros (
    id_Teatro INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_Teatro VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Como una Obra puede presentarse en varios Teatros, y un Teatro puede tener varias Obras hago una tabla de union M:M entre Obras y Teatros y hago que la Clave Primaria sea compuesta.

```
CREATE TABLE Obras_Teatros (
    id_Obra INTEGER UNSIGNED,
    id_Teatro INTEGER UNSIGNED,
        PRIMARY KEY (id_Obra, id_Teatro),
        FOREIGN KEY (id_Obra) REFERENCES Obras (id_Obra),
        FOREIGN KEY (id_Teatro) REFERENCES Teatros (id_Teatro)
);
```

Hasta aca todo bien. Mi duda aparece cuando quiero relacionar a un Artista con una Obra y un Teatro tomando la tabla de union Obras_Teatros. No se si es posible ni correcto, y si fuera el caso, no logro dar con la manera de hacer la tabla con sentencias relacionando la clave compuesta como foranea en la tabla Artistas_Obras...

La idea seria algo asi aunque no se como escribirla correctamente (ni si es correcto hacerlo)...:

> CREATE TABLE Artistas_Obras (
> id_Artista ,      --seria clave foranea de Artistas
> id_Obra_Teatro ,  --seria clave compuesta y foranea de Obras_Teatros );

Y ademas que no se pueda duplicar la combinacion id_Artista id_Obra_Teatro

Si alguien me puede orientar estaria muy agradecido.

Comment: Agrega a obras_teatro un id unico autogenerado y te ahorras todo el problema de tus claves....

Comment: eso lo pense, pero tengo entendido que una tabla de union no debe tener clave primaria, perderia la razon de ser y podria duplicar obras con teatros...

Comment: tengo entendido, por donde??? o sea, vos podes hacer lo que quieras... la clave, es para ubicar mas facil las cosas... y para no tener este desbole que tenes ahora... tambien podrias poner un constrain de indice unico que evite que se repita....

Comment: Es mas, tambien podrias no tener ni una key, y controlar todo por el software (mi metodo preferido particularmente)...

Comment: Lo tengo entendido por lo aprendido en normalizacion, quiza lo entendi mal.

Esto me interesa "podrias poner un constrain de indice unico que evite que se repita", podrias darme un poco mas de informacion sobre como aprender de este tema?

La parte de "controlar todo por el software", no entendi a que te referis.

Comment: alguien carga los datos en la db.. usualmente, un programa... las reglas podrian estar en el programa tambien... ahora, si esto es un ejercicio, entonces eso no cuenta... si agregas un indice unico con esos dos campos, ahi tenes un constrain

Answer (score 0):

Como te dicen en los comentarios la implementación que sigas es muy libre y existen multiples soluciones válidas.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, (y tratando de mantener una BD normalizada) no hay ningún problema con que un conjunto de claves foráneas formen una clave primaria
siempre y cuando estas columnas (atributos) sigan la forma normal de [Boyce-Codd](http://19e37.com/blog/formas-normales-1fn-2fn-3fn/).

Por ejemplificar, si los **nombres** de los teatros son únicos son **clave candidata** para la tabla **teatro** y no es necesario "inventarse" un "id" artificial pudiendo usar el atributo nombre como clave.

Por concluir muestro algo de código. Con esto deberías poder crear la relación que pides para la tabla Autor_Obra_Teatro en la que los ids de todos forman una clave primaria:

```sql
--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `artistas`
--

CREATE TABLE `artistas` (
  `id_Artista` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_Artista` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `artista_obra_teatro`
--

CREATE TABLE `artista_obra_teatro` (
  `id_Artista` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_Obra` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_Teatro` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `obras`
--

CREATE TABLE `obras` (
  `id_Obra` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_Obra` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `obra_teatro`
--

CREATE TABLE `obra_teatro` (
  `id_Obra` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_Teatro` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `teatros`
--

CREATE TABLE `teatros` (
  `id_teatro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_teatro` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `artistas`
--
ALTER TABLE `artistas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_Artista`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `artista_obra_teatro`
--
ALTER TABLE `artista_obra_teatro`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_Artista`,`id_Obra`,`id_Teatro`),
  ADD KEY `id_Obra` (`id_Obra`),
  ADD KEY `id_Teatro` (`id_Teatro`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `obras`
--
ALTER TABLE `obras`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_Obra`) USING HASH;

--
-- Indices de la tabla `obra_teatro`
--
ALTER TABLE `obra_teatro`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_Obra`,`id_Teatro`),
  ADD KEY `id_Teatro` (`id_Teatro`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `teatros`
--
ALTER TABLE `teatros`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_teatro`);

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `artista_obra_teatro`
--
ALTER TABLE `artista_obra_teatro`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `artista_obra_teatro_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_Artista`) REFERENCES `artistas` (`id_Artista`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `artista_obra_teatro_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_Obra`) REFERENCES `obras` (`id_Obra`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `artista_obra_teatro_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_Teatro`) REFERENCES `teatros` (`id_teatro`);

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `obra_teatro`
--
ALTER TABLE `obra_teatro`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `obra_teatro_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_Obra`) REFERENCES `obras` (`id_Obra`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `obra_teatro_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_Teatro`) REFERENCES `teatros` (`id_teatro`);
COMMIT;
```

Por último una recomendacion. Para ver normalización de forma autodidacta y sin mucha complicación puedes probar phpmyadmin (Usando la pila de [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html) por ejemplo) u otro entorno que te permita *jugar* y probar lo que se te ocurra de forma rápida y visual. Phpmyadmin permite operaciones con interfaz grafica a la vez que enseña el SQL que aplica y usar un "diseñador gráfico" que muestra las relaciones de las tablas entre otras herramientas:

[image: diseñador gráfico]

Espero que sirva de ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, voy a ir probando hasta dar con la solución mas optima. Pero que sepas que me aclaro mucho tu ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

> Mi duda aparece cuando quiero relacionar a un Artista con una Obra y
> un Teatro tomando la tabla de union Obras_Teatros ...

Para ello necesitarás ciertamente una tabla `Artistas_Obras`, sólo que en esa tabla no debes embrollar las cosas metiendo a la columna `id_Obra_Teatro`.

Y es que el mismo nombre de la tabla ya te lo dice: **`Artistas_Obras`**, por tanto, ahí deben ir las columnas `id_Artista` y `id_Obra` y, eso sí, debes declarar una restricción de unicidad para evitar que el mismo artista sea dueño de la misma obra más de una vez.

Luego, sólo tienes que poner los `JOIN` de forma correcta, para obtener el dato de cada cosa.

Te dejo un fiddle completo y funcionando, si observas, en el `SELECT` se obtienen los datos de todas las tablas.

```
CREATE TABLE Artistas 
(
    id_Artista INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_Artista VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Obras 
(
    id_Obra INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_Obra VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Teatros 
(
    id_Teatro INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_Teatro VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Artistas_Obras 
( 
  id_Artista INTEGER UNSIGNED, 
  id_Obra INTEGER UNSIGNED, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id_Artista, id_Obra),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_Artista) REFERENCES Artistas (id_Artista),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_Obra) REFERENCES Obras (id_Obra)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Obras_Teatros 
(
    id_Obra INTEGER UNSIGNED,
    id_Teatro INTEGER UNSIGNED,
        PRIMARY KEY (id_Obra, id_Teatro),
        FOREIGN KEY (id_Obra) REFERENCES Obras (id_Obra),
        FOREIGN KEY (id_Teatro) REFERENCES Teatros (id_Teatro)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO `Artistas` VALUES 
  (1,'Artista 1'),
  (2,'Artista 2');
```

```
INSERT INTO `Obras` VALUES 
  (1,'Obra 1'),
  (2,'Obra 2');
```

```
INSERT INTO `Teatros` VALUES 
  (1,'Teatro 1'),
  (2,'Teatro 2');
```

```
INSERT INTO `Artistas_Obras` VALUES 
  (1,1),
  (2,2);
```

```
INSERT INTO `Obras_Teatros` VALUES 
  (1,1),
  (2,2);
```

```
SELECT 
  `a`.`id_Artista`,
  `a`.`nombre_Artista`,
  `o`.`id_Obra`,
  `o`.`nombre_Obra`,
  `t`.`id_Teatro`,
  `t`.`nombre_Teatro`  
FROM `Artistas_Obras` AS `ao`
INNER JOIN `Artistas` AS `a` ON `ao`.`id_Artista`= `a`.`id_Artista`
INNER JOIN `Obras` AS `o` ON `ao`.`id_Obra`= `o`.`id_Obra`
INNER JOIN `Obras_Teatros` AS `ot` ON `ao`.`id_Obra`= `ot`.`id_Obra`
INNER JOIN `Teatros` AS `t` ON `ot`.`id_Teatro`= `t`.`id_Teatro`
  ;
```

| id_Artista | nombre_Artista | id_Obra | nombre_Obra | id_Teatro | nombre_Teatro |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Artista 1 | 1 | Obra 1 | 1 | Teatro 1 |
| 2 | Artista 2 | 2 | Obra 2 | 2 | Teatro 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iwsFE6A-)

---

#### Post-Data

Convendría que definas en tus tablas las restricciones de integridad referencial que aplican para cada caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me sirve mucho para seguir aprendiendo.

Answer (score 0):

Las soluciones propuestas estan bien, pero nadie respondió a la pregunta del OP. ¿Se puede hacer FK a múltiples columnas?

Sí se puede. Pero recuerda que el sentido de una FK es relacionar info en una tabla mediante una referencia a otra tabla tal   que la BBDD se ocupe de mantener la integridad relacional, por ejemplo impidiendo que la tabla que referencia tenga registros no-nulos sin una contraparte en la tabla referenciada. Te permite además condicionar la respueta a modificaciones en la tabla referenciada, propagar un camibio de ids a la tabla referente, reaccionar al borrado eliminando los registros en la tabla referente o bien haciendolos  null.

Cuál de esos propósitos estarías resolviendo con una FK compuesta, que no se pueda hacer con tres pivotes? Ninguno. Y cuántos problemas adicionales a cambio? Todos.

#### Al grano

Para referenciar  dos columnas en otra tabla necesitas dos columnas, no crees? Si tu propósito fuera propagar un cambio en una tupla `obra_id, teatro_id`, cómo podría saber la BBDD qué registros de `Artista_Obra` modificar si tuviera que buscarlos en un solo campo? A lo mejor tenías en mente que podría funcionar con la concatenación de los valores, pero eso no existe.

Si la tabla Artista_Obra tuviera los campos obra_id y teatro_id podriás hacer

```
 ALTER TABLE artista_obra
 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_pesadilla
    FOREIGN KEY (obra_id, teatro_id)
     REFERENCES Teatros_Obras (obra_id,teatro_id)
```

Ahora pensemos en unos datos de ejemplo.

**Artistas**

| id | nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Robert de Niro |
| 2 | Al Pacino |
| 3 | Marlon Brando |

**Obras**

| id | nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | El padrino |
| 2 | El padrino II |
| 3 | The Score |

(The score nadie la conoce, pero salen Marlon Brando y Robert de Niro)

**Obra_Artista (cada película cuenta con dos de los 3 actores disponibles)**

| id | id_obra | id_artista |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 3 |

Esas películas estuvieron en todos los cines, pero vamos a inventar 3 teatros famosos y decir que todas estuvieron ahí. O sea, 9 registros

**Teatros**

| id | nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | La Scala |
| 2 | Teatro Chino |
| 3 | El Coliseo |

---

**Teatro_Obra (3 películas x 3 teatros)**

| id | id_obra | id_teatro |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 | 1 |
| 8 | 3 | 2 |
| 9 | 3 | 3 |

Si cada obra se presentó en 3 tratros, y cada artista apareció en dos obras, cada artista apareció en 6 presentaciones (la combinación de una obra en un teatro).

6 presentaciones multiplicado por 3 artistas es 18, justo lo que te daria cruzar las dos tablas pivote.

```
  SELECT id_artista,id_obra,id_teatro 
     FROM obra_artista JOIN teatro_obra USING (id_obra)
```

Si tu inquietud es preservar la unicidad de las combinaciones, eso ya lo tienes sin meterte en un pivote de llaves compuestas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, sobre todo a que se puede hacer FK a múltiples columnas, mas alla de si es util o correcto. Voy a probar el ejemplo que me sugeris. Saludos